# Form only sending the last row from a form and not the selected one

Tags: php

I have a table where each row in the table has a button that allows you to delete that particular row from the database. Although somehow my form only submits the last row and no the one I selected. Please ignore the deprecated tags, well aware of the issues.

```
<?php
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking");

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {

                ?>

                <form class='table-form' id='form' method='post'>

                    <tr>

                    <input id="bookid" type="hidden" name="bookid" value="<?php echo ($row['booking_id']); ?>" />

                    <td>

                    <?php echo ($row['booking_id']);?>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo ($row['user_id']); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo ($row['event_id']); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo ($row['payment_type']); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo ($row['booking_date']); ?>
                    </td>
                        <center><button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Cancel</button><center>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>




                <?php
                }
                ?>


                </form>

            </table>
        </div>

        <?php


            if (isset($_POST['bookid'])){

                $id =  ($_POST['bookid']);

                $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM booking
                WHERE booking_id = '$id'");

        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you preffer programing this way, move `</form>` above

```
<?php
}
?>
```

(to cycle body).

Your code needs a lot of clean up, style cleaning and html validation. :-P

Comment: This method works, although my buttons and the table is all misplaced. I know my code is terrible, just getting the basic working before I clean up

Comment: Of course. You can not put form cross the table. Use only one form tag above the table.